# Unable to select all data from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing something really strange.

In a table (T) containning 400 000 records.

When selecting this:

```
select top 150000 * from T
```

I got answer in 3 secondes

but if I take them all, I stop the request after 5 minutes without having the result.

Any idea about this problem ?

thx,

Pit

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: How you select the data? Using SMS?

Comment: Why are you trying to get 400.000 records to the client?
Can you take a look at the query plan?

Comment: @Arman As I see the indexes will be useless in this case. There are not any where and join predicates.  We just get ALL filds from entire table.

Comment: About ndx:I got one clustered index on the primary key and severall other ndx on foreign key.

Answer (score 4):

The main area to look for the cause are:

1. Disk IO
2. Cache hit ratio
3. A block on a page of the table because of other processes ( Add WITH(NOLOCK) table hint to your query)
4. Network bottleneck (if going to client off the db server)

I agree with Arman that the indexes are not needed and each page of the table must be read.

Comment: I can't upvote as I am an unregistered user but would strongly suspect number 3

Comment: So is it blocking when the request tries to lock tha table it wants to read ? Also something stange: there are 2 ndx i didn't create on table and the estimates plan takes one of them for the result. So i'll detroy those 2 ndx and retest